# Share popup window auto close if post has been deleted

Tags: bug, review, share-this, russian-stackoverflow

During [review](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/151928) [a post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643728/176217) has been deleted. Clicking on the "share" link leads to an appearing and immediately closing popup window:

> [image: auto-close]

If you open [the post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643728/176217) now (i.e. already deleted, need 10k on ruSO) the share link works fine.